# Writing only circumflex (^) character in Latex

Tags: latex

I'm trying to write an equation in Latex which uses the circumflex character as an operator. The whole thing should look something like this:
a ^ b

I tried stuff like `$a \^ b$` or `$a \hat{ } b$` but the first one didn't work at all and the second one didn't look nice (see image [result for second method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/14bAi.png)). What would be the right way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\[
a \,^{\wedge}\, b
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Looks good. And by making it a new command typing it will be easier. Thanks alot!

Comment: The symbol in the text is a wedge, not a circumflex. So, if the text is extracted from the PDF (like by copy-pasting), there will be a potentially wrong character.